# UIVideoEditorController know the start and end point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, uivideoeditorcontroller

I am trying to use the `UIVideoEditorController` to be a UI so user can choose the place to split the video into 2 pieces. The problem with the `UIVideoEditorController` is that I cannot know where user chooses the start position and end positions. Does anybody know how I can get these information from `UIVideoEditorController`? Or does it have any third party library that replicate the user interface of `UIVideoEditorController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No by using **UIVideoEditorController** you cannot get start position and end positions whatever the user had selected. And still now there is no third party library.

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively do this task with image picker controller 
after knowing the start and end point split the video or whatever you want

```
-(void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info 
    {


            NSNumber *start = [info objectForKey:@"_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart"];
            NSNumber *end = [info objectForKey:@"_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd"];
    }
```

Set allows editing yes
and this will give the start and end point of user selected part for iOS 5